# trying to connect to heroku database and even configured pg_hba.conf file with all credentials but getting this error

Tags: web-deployment, postgresql-12

psql -h [hostname] -U [user] [database]
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "***.***.***.**", user "[user]", database "[database]", SSL off

psql -h ***.***.***.*** -U [user] [database]
psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
        Is the server running on host "**.**.**.**" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: What you have in pg_hba.conf? a * will not be a correct entry.

Comment: also can you confirm what is the status of postgresql-12 service